# IntelliJ - Java Gradle Run/Debug with args

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Spring application with Gradle and I run/debug it with `bootRun` task.
This looks for the class with `main` method.

But sometimes I have to pass an argument for it, through `main(String[] args)`.

How can I do it from Run/Debug dialog? I tried VM options and Arguments, but when breakpoint get at args, it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Command-Line Arguments in Spring Boot](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments) document describes, pass it for `bootRun` task as:

`-Pargs=<arg1>,<arg2>`

and in `build.gradle`:

```
bootRun {
  if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
      args project.args.split(',')
  }
}
```