# How do I use Gradle bootRun with --args in Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Gradle 4.9 introduced the `--args` parameter to `bootRun`, which I can use easily from the command-line, but how do I use this from a Run/Debug configuration in Intellij 2018?

With a Gradle build set to run the `bootRun` task on my project in Intellij, I've tried the following arguments in the Run/Debug Configurations screen without any success:

- `--args 'foo'`
- `--args='foo'`
- `--args=foo`

Output from Intellij:

```
9:18:56 AM: Executing task 'bootRun --args='foo''...

Unknown command-line option '--args'.
9:18:57 AM: Task execution finished 'bootRun --args='foo''.
```

[A similar question documents the older syntax for doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156193/intellij-java-gradle-run-debug-with-args).

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196952

Comment: did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, I just chose to debug by running the Spring Boot Application class instead of via Gradle.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can add your args to `Tasks` as `bootRun --args='foo'` in IDEA's `Run/Debug Configurations`.

My task is `run --args='-h'` and it works for me

Comment: This is funny, but it actually works (currently with IDEA 2019.x). I'd not expect it, but it does. Not sure how you got that downvote. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, @Linsama's workaround **will not work with multiple arguments**. For example, `run --args='--arg1 --arg2'` will not work.

For multiple arguments, you have to move the entire thing in the Arguments field and leave the Tasks field blank.

This will work:

Tasks:

Arguments: `run --args='--arg1 --arg2'`

Comment: Amazing workaround, thank you!
It's funny that either way it says `"Executing task 'run --args=myargs'...`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use gradle properties.

In intellij Arguments field add `-Pargs=--myArg=value`

Then in your `build.gradle` add

```
bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        args project.args.split(',')
    }
}
```

They should be now accesible using `ApplicationArguments` inside your application.