# Passing arguments to 'gradle run' in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to a program executed via Gradle run task in IntelliJ IDEA?

In the terminal, I can simply do this:

`./gradlew run --args="-hello"`, which will pass the command line argument '-hello' to the program as expected.

However, if I add --args="-hello" to the IDEA Run Configuration (as in the image below), all I get is an error, which reads "failed", with this output:

```
10:08:50: Executing task 'run --args="-hello"'...
10:08:50: Task execution finished 'run --args="-hello"'.
```

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

A similar question, but no good answer: [How do I use Gradle bootRun with --args in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267489/how-do-i-use-gradle-bootrun-with-args-in-intellij)

Comment: Try to just specify `-hello`. Try also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196952#focus=streamItem-27-3180718.0-0

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, the link contained the answer!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue in IntelliJ IDEA: [Cannot use Gradle 4.9 --args option in "Arguments" field of a Gradle run configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196952#focus=streamItem-27-3180718.0-0)

The solution that worked best for me was to insert the run command in the **Arguments** section:
[image]

If I place the line `run --args="-username=john -password=wayne"` in the **Tasks** field (as also suggested in the link), it will complain about unmatched quotes due to the space between the two arguments.

Comment: There is no 'Arguments' section for me (would place screenshot, but doesn't work for some reason)

Comment: See the answer below. You can add gradle arguments after the gradle task name (e.g., "bootRun --args="--debug")

It's surprising. I agree.

Comment: I haven't used IDEA in a while. The UI might have changed. See the answer from JMax.

Answer (score 11):

Arguments can be passed by adding --args="" to the run section.

[image]